# I have managed to create a view statment with all the columns I need. Can I use it to somehow get also the table view that I need?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

In `Table` there are 120 columns. I just need 117 columns to be listed. This is my script that selects all the columns that I need.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Table'
  AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( 'ColumnA' )
  AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( 'ColumnB' )
  AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( 'ColumnC' )
```

Can I use this script to generate the table that I need? How? If not, is there other solution (other than writing down all the 120 and just deleting those 3)?

Comment: Why do you not want to just list the 117 columns you want? Is it that you don't want to type out 117 columns names? If that is the case, you can just right-click on the table Object Explorer panel of SQL Server Management Studio and choose "Select Top 1000 Rows" and you will get a SELECT statement with all of the columns listed out. You can then remove the ones you don't want.

Comment: It's just because I want to use those columns in another app. Bonus : If I type all 117 columns and I somehow want to update the table and add or remove a column, I should also update the script. Having the posibility to have a script that just removes those 3 particular columns will be pretty nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use dynamic sql

```
DECLARE @col_list VARCHAR(max)= ''

SET @col_list = (SELECT ',' + COLUMN_NAME
                 FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                 WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'Table'
                        AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( 'ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnC' )
                 FOR xml path (''))

SELECT Stuff(@col_list, 1, 1, '')

EXEC ('select '+@col_list+' from yourtable ')
```

Comment: TOP 10 clause can be an issue.